# Screenshot is black in Mac OS X SL

Tags: mac, screenshot

When I press cmd+shift+3 in desktop saves black 1400x900 file 
Command: defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true
Does not work

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be somehow related to running multiple displays. I had a situation where the screen grabs were mostly black, but a tiny portion of the window I wanted to capture was still visible albeit very offset to one side. It's as if the screen grab functionality did not realize that the external display had disconnected and was grabbing a portion off an inactive screen buffer. It's possible that the resolution change resets this.

Comment: Yeah, I just had the same problem. Once I reset my resolution I fixed the problem! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you are viewing a "protected" video stream, eg. a DVD Viewer set to full screen.  If you were not full screen, the DVD viewer would be a black box, with your desktop (or other images) showing up correctly...

A full screen DVD session would probably appear as just a black box...

Answer (score 1):

Generally such a problem occurs on 'Hackintoshes' which do not have QE/CI (aka Quartz Extreme (QE) and Core Image (CI)). This is due to the non-availability of Apple Provided Graphic Card Drivers on these machines [more info](http://prasys.co.cc/tag/qeci-snow-leopard/)

So, either you are on not on a original mac, or somehow your graphics drivers have gone bonkers.

Comment: if have MacOS 10.6 on MacBook Pro MB133. I've got a solution of black screen: you need in preferences change resolution and set it back

Comment: @user38766: If you found a solution to your own question, you can post it as an answer so others with the same problem will know how to fix it.

Comment: Changing the resolution worked for me on my MacBook Pro. I didn't even bother leaving the preferences window -- just clicked on a different resolution and clicked back. All good. Thanks!